# "The filename, directory name or volume level syntax is incorrect while running kafka for the first time

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to install kafka in my system; but I am getting the below exception.

Exception : "The filename, directory name or volume level syntax is incorrect ".

I am doing the following steps:
1. Downloaded kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0 and extracted in a folder.
2.  I have modified the server.properties  for log.dirs
log.dirs= D:\Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0\kafka-logs

3. then from CMD  i am triggering the below.

.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If on windows box, shouldn't you specify the directory as `D:\\Kafka\\kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0\\kafka-logs` or `D:/Kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/kafka-logs`?

Comment: I tried that also. but it did not work. not sure why the problem is happening.